# Is firebase JavaScript SDK secure over network?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Setting up Firebase Web JavaScript project. Firebase Authentication allows to authenticate users. But are Firebase SDK methods secure over various networks/routers ?

I am new to Firebase. I am trying to understand different functions/features provided by Firebase. For example, Firebase Authentication ([Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)) helps to login/logout and much more a user.
In one of its methods ([Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)) I can see it uses input username/password: `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` to check if credentials are correct. So, when this information moves over networks to back end instances, is this secure ?

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

It would be great if someone can share how the data is moved across with firebase js sdks and if it's secure ?

Comment: How do you think it's different any other web application with authentication? They all need to send email and password. You can encrypt it on browser but encryption algorithm will be in same browser and reachable

Answer (score 2):

All traffic to and from Firebase services through the provided SDKs is encrypted in transit.  It can't be modified or decrypted, as is the case for any communications using [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), which is a very common global internet standard for secure communications.